# What does the Clamtk network setting do?

Tags: malware, clamav, clamtk

[image]

As mentioned in the question, what does the network setting for clamtk do? It seems that it is not clearly documented in the clamav/clamtk documentations. I have basic knowledge of what is a IP address and port however I do not understand how does is related to anti-malware software. I am also unsure of why is there a "No Proxy" option.

Does the network setting mean that clamtk is scanning for malwares in the network other than the host machine?

I am assuming environment settings means the default setting on the host machine, however I cannot find official documentation to confirm this.

Comment: Some users may need to set a proxy for outbound connections. ClamTk needs to connect out for antivirus signature updates and to check for newer versions of both itself and the engine. This is set in the option you have questioned. [reference](http://clamtk.sourceforge.net/help/proxy-preferences-clamtk.html)

Comment: Thanks, i think you should post is as an answer.

Comment: @yangmandi done. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some users of ClamTK may need to set a proxy for outbound connections and this is the place to do it.

ClamTK needs to connect out for for antivirus signature updates and to check for newer versions of both itself and the engine.

This can be environment settings or you can set it manually.

This is set in the option in your question.

[reference](http://clamtk.sourceforge.net/help/proxy-preferences-clamtk.html)